# Openrefine: select XML based on child node value

Tags: xml, xpath, openrefine

I have got columns in openrefine that contain this kind of value that I got from a web service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
        <result>
            <nnt>2010BOR30012</nnt>
            <ppn>146708164</ppn>
            <typerecord>m</typerecord>
        </result>
        <result>
            <nnt>2010BOR30012</nnt>
            <ppn>159823226</ppn>
            <typerecord>v</typerecord>
        </result>
</results>
```

I'd like to be able from this XML to get the `<ppn>` value that is contained in the `<result>` tag where `<typerecord>` is v for example. I have tried different things based on parseHtml and select but for the time being I have not been able to find a solution to achieve that.

Update following comment from @Tomalak : things I have been trying are mainly:

- trying to combine parseHtml() and select() with some kind of xpath, I don't thinkg it is possible but if something proves me it's wrong I will be happy :)
- trying to loop through each `<result>` and test each of them for the subtag `<typerecord>`, using somethinkg like : `forEach(value.parseHtml().select("result"), e, "<xml>" + e.replace("\n", "").replace("\/", "/") + "</xml>")` my goal being for the last part of this forEach to get something I am able to parse using parseHtml (that's why I have been trying to add the surrounding `<xml>` tag but it does'nt work, I get something like `[ "<xml><result> <nnt> 1989BOR30027 <\/nnt> <ppn> 006608523 <\/ppn> <typerecord> m <\/typerecord><\/result><\/xml>" ]` that can't be parsed because of the extra \ that I have not been able to remove.

Meanwhile I have found a way to fix my issue, even if I would prefer a solution using grel, this one using jython works so I am adding it there but this question remains opened to a Grel answer!

So the jython script that seems to do the job is :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
element = ET.fromstring(value)

resultsList = element.findall("./result")

for result in resultsList:
    typerecord = result.find("typerecord")
    if typerecord.text == "m":
        return result.find("ppn").text
```

I am pretty sure there is an easier solution but I still have not been able to find it!

Comment: If you have tried different things, show your code so far. (If you have no code, try different things first.)

Comment: No option in your web service for getting the result in Json? It's easier to parse.

Comment: @Tomalak I have been trying to pass xpath to select, will give example tonight when back on the PC where I have done my tests

Comment: @EttoreRizza No option for Json correctly formatted at the moment :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ettore - in this case Jython is going to give the easiest solution. But if you want to do it with GREL my solution is:

Using GREL and parseHtml
Despite its name you can parse XML with the parseHtml function. The select function accepts jsoup selectors

```
value.parseHtml().select("result")
```

Will get all the result elements

To select only the result elements containing typerecord=v you have to combine this with a filter function:
    filter(value.parseHtml().select("result"),e,e.select("typerecord")[0].ownText()=="v")

This will give you an array of result elements where typerecord=v

So finally you can iterate through these to select ppn value:

```
forEach(filter(value.parseHtml().select("result"),e,e.select("typerecord")[0].ownText()=="v"), f, f.select("ppn")[0].ownText())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many solutions in GREL, for example :

```
forEachIndex(value.parseHtml().select("typerecord"), i, v, if(v.htmlText()=="v",value.parseHtml().select("ppn")[i].htmlText(),null)).join(' ')
```

or

```
with(value.parseHtml().select('result'), e, filter(e.join('|').split('|'), v, v.contains('v')))[0].parseHtml().select("ppn")[0].htmlText()
```

or

```
forEach(value.parseHtml().select("result"),e,if(e.select("typerecord")[0].htmlText()=="v", e.select("ppn")[0].ownText(), null)).join('')
```

But I don't like this kind of Russian dolls. Your own solution in Jython with `xml.etree` is much clearer. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I had never used it before so prefered to use Grel but now that I have found the solution I think that Jython might be ok. I am still not convinced by the jython editor in openrefine but that will do the job for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Get ppn node, then filter by "back to parent / typerecord / value=v":

`//result/ppn[../typerecord/text()='v']`